# Using CSS selectors, is it possible to differentiate between these 2 code snippets?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-selectors, pattern-matching

**Using CSS selectors**, is it possible to differentiate *in any way* between the following two code snippets?  By differentiate, I mean selecting any part (or the whole) of either snippet, but not the other.

```
<span role="presentation">
   <span class="test" role="presentation" test-text="foo">bar</span>
</span>
```

and

```
<span role="presentation">
   <span class="test" role="presentation" test-text="foo">bar</span>
   baz
</span>
```

The web browser being used is only Firefox, so Mozilla-only features are also acceptable.

### EDIT 1:

***Additional details that may help answerers:***

More complex versions of both of the above HTML snippets are present in the code. I've isolated it down to simplify this question, as everything else will be relevant. The only difference is the string (***baz*** in this simplified example) in the outer `span`.

I'm looking for a selector that will match anything in one snippet, without matching anything in the other snippet. (I'm not sure if this is possible, so I'm trying to be maximally flexible with answers.) I can't change the upstream HTML, but I can change the CSS.

### EDIT 2:

***I've been asked to add more details and specifics, as this may impact the answer.***

I think this will really help clarify: My goal is to hide the string *bar* **if and only if** *baz* is present in the upstream HTML (as shown in the second code snippet).

I'm good with hiding the entire `span.test` element or just the ***bar*** text string within it... either way is fine.

Regarding hiding ***bar***, I'm open to all possibilities of hiding it so it takes up no space.  I'm thinking of `display: none` or `width: 0`, but anything that results in it not taking up any space when ***baz*** is present is good.

### EDIT 3:

Just a quick update: I went through the upstream code in depth, and it looks like ***bar*** will always be whitespace.  I'm not sure if that opens any doors, but if it does, I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: define *differentiate*

Comment: @TemaniAfif Any method to select any part (or the whole) of either snippet, but not the other.

Comment: to select and do what?

Comment: @TemaniAfif If I can select with CSS, then I can apply CSS declarations to that selection.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: well, still not clear to me what you want to achieve. Probably other users will better understand

Comment: @TemaniAfif But you're one of the smartest! :)  More complex versions of both of the above HTML snippets are present in the code. I've isolated it down to simplify this question, as everything else will be relevant. The only difference is the string (*baz* in this simplified example) in the outer `span`. I'm looking for a selector that will match *anything* in one snippet, without matching anything in the other snippet.  Does that make more sense? (I'm not sure if this is possible, so I'm trying to be maximally flexible with answers.) I can't change the upstream HTML, but I can change the CSS.

Comment: something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m8b9taLp/1/? where only *baz* is red?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hmmm... interesting... that pretty much satisfies the question as written... now I need to think about it to see if I can use your idea to do what I want.  It's pretty much the exact opposite of what I had in mind, which might work fine, because I might be able to add a `:not()` psuedo-class or think about it more using the direction you graciously provided.  It's going to take me a little bit to think about it, because you approached it exactly opposite of what I was thinking (which may be a good thing, because I wasn't having success yet).

Comment: the styles you are applying can also be relevant to the quesiton. In other words, there is no generic way or trivial code to achieve what you want. We can only find very specific ideas to your very specific case.

Comment: @TemaniAfif FYI, what I've been thinking I need to do is write a selector to match one of the `span`s with class of `test` without selecting the other one.  I can't think of any way to do that, as I can't change the upstream HTML.  Can you?  Regarding your last comment, let me edit the question to make it more specific.  I hope I can successfully add clarity while still making it short enough to be readable.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I updated the question based on your comments.  Your comments have been *very* helpful in making the question more specific, hopefully without closing any doors to workable answers.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A very hacky idea to use with caution (or to not use at all ...). Only work if `baz` is longer than `bar`

```css
[role=presentation] {
  text-indent: -13px; /* based on "bar" text */
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
[role=presentation]::before {
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
   left:0;
   background:#fff;
    z-index: -1;
}

[role=presentation] [role=presentation] {
  text-indent: 0;
  z-index:-2;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 7px)); /* the 7px is the whitespace*/
  margin-right:0;
}
[role=presentation] [role=presentation]::before {
  content:none;
}


/* irrelevant, simply to separate both elements */
.extra {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="extra">
  <span role="presentation">
   <span class="test" role="presentation" test-text="foo">bar</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="extra">
  <span role="presentation">
   <span class="test" role="presentation" test-text="foo">bar</span> baz
  </span>
</div>

<div class="extra">
  <span role="presentation">
   <span class="test" role="presentation" test-text="foo">bar</span> another baz
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Temani!  That's very clever.  I'm looking at what you did now.  Is there any reason you chose to use `px` units instead of `em`?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket no particular reason, In all the cases it's not a generic value so the unit won't make a lot of difference

Comment: Thanks.  In the second line, isn't the number of pixels hardcoded for the length of *bar* in a specific font?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket yes it's the "not" generic value that you have to update based on the *bar* (font, font-size, letter spacing, etc)

Comment: Got it.  That shouldn't pose a problem, as I can control all those with CSS.  Would  using `em` units make it automatically reflect the font/font-size/etc. being used?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket only if the text is always the same and the font family always the same (Note that em is a vertical measurement not an horizontal one)

Comment: Sounds good.  I think I may be able to control all those factors.  I was actually thinking of proposing using `ch` units, as they are a horizontal unit, but for reasons that I've never understood, people seem to frequently use `em` when they should really be using `ch` (and I didn't want to get sidetracked on that wild goose chase!).

Comment: Any reason you can think of *not* to use `ch` units?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket `ch` is only useful when dealing with monospace font because ch is the measuremen of `0` and in monospace font all the character have the same width. So even with `ch` you will need a particular value based on the text and the font.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using a monospace font for this.  I sometimes forget that you're amazing, but not a mind reader!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the 2 code blocks is that in the latter there is the text node `baz`.

However, text nodes cannot be selected.

Even if `baz` was wrapped by an HTML element it wouldn't help select a previous sibling or a parent element. It is just not possible.

The only way to select them that I can think of is by the position of `span[role="presentation"]` in a parent element.

For instance, if `span[role="presentation"]` were children of the same parent you could select them with pseudo classes such as `:first-child`, `:last-child`, `:nth-child()` etc...

```css
div > span[role="presentation"]:first-child {
  background: red;
}

div > span[role="presentation"]:last-child {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span role="presentation">
     <span class="test" role="presentation" test-text="foo">bar</span>
  </span>

  <span role="presentation">
     <span class="test" role="presentation" test-text="foo">bar</span> baz
  </span>
</div>
```

I'm not aware of any Mozilla-only feature that would allow to do it differently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fabrizio.  I'm not sure why someone else downvoted it right away, because it's very well-written.  I upvoted based on answer quality, even if I don't yet know if it is totally accurate.  Your conclusion is the same as mine, but I'm hoping I'm wrong because it would really help me to be able to do this.  Regarding using the order of the outer `span`'s, it's a good idea, but unfortunately, I can't use that.  Upstream feeds me thousands of the outer `span`'s, and any of them can have a ***baz*** inside.

Comment: Probably because the example I gave is not very pertinent to **EDIT 2** which I didn't see before posting. In any case I still think the first part answers the question but yeah, I'd be happy to be proved wrong.